# How to suppress Jenkins or ios SDK compilation log

Tags: iphone, xcode, jenkins

I am using jenkins for xcode iPhone app build purpose and succeed to build it.After build I need to parse all the logs.So that I want minimum logs to be printed on jenkins console window.

**Screenshot for jenkins**

[image]

**Or you can see it on xcode as well as**

[image]

Is there anyway to prevent ios sdk to print so much compilation log.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to 'parse all the logs'? Is this an automated step or a manual one?

Comment: in jenkins to catch up finish with success.Due to some reason we cannot use postBuild action otherwise that will be perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

Could you execute your build/compile steps outside of jenkins (calling the exe's directly) and then simply redirect that output to a specific file (or something null)?

I do something similar with Jenkins where I'm using Nant to perform the actual build, and my calls to the compiler actions create specific log files at each step.